# Creating a thread that will execute after delay

Tags: java, multithreading

How would I create a thread that will execute after a delay of s seconds?

I would like other processes to run while the thread is waiting.

For example, I would like to create the thread, then print out several other strings, then after s seconds, the thread will run.

What I don't need is the whole program to wait for s seconds, then everything happens. I need processes to run while the delay is ticking.

Thanks!

~Java preferred

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: In java (and many other languages) you can schedule threads. Check out [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `ScheduledExecutorService`. See the example below.

```
System.out.println("some stuff");

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final Runnable task = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("do something");
    }
};
Future<?> futureHandle = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

System.out.println("some other stuff");
```

The task is scheduled with a fixed delay of 10 seconds, so you'll get output for the print statements not in the `Runnable` followed by the one in the `Runnable` every 10 seconds.

The output in this example is

some stuff
some other stuff
do something
do something
...

with the "do something" lines occurring at 10 sec. intervals after an initial 10 sec. delay.

To stop it, you can create a "stop" task to put some kind of logic in, and register that.

```
final Runnable stopTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        futureHandle.cancel(true); // true: interrupt if necessary
    }
};
long delay = // some number, how long to wait before invoking the stop task
scheduler.schedule(stopTask, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS).get(); // wait if necessary and get the future result
scheduler.shutdown(); // shutdown on completion
```

EDIT

If you just need the task to run once, as pointed out in the comments, consider a `TimerTask`:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();

final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("timer task");
        timer.cancel(); // stop timer after execution
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 1000); // schedule task with delay of 1000ms
```

Comment: I think that "shedule" would do according to description

Comment: Don't think he was looking for continous printing (every 10 seconds), and creating a stop task seems excessive. Try [`java.util.Timer#schedule(TimerTask, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-), where the `long` is the delay in ms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one working example with Thread.sleep():

```
public class DelayThread implements Runnable {

    private final int DELAY;

    public DelayThread(int delay) {
        this.DELAY = delay;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            System.out.println("task executed");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new DelayThread(2000));
        thread1.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new DelayThread(2000));
        thread2.start();
        System.out.println("All threads are started");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take look into [quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). This is very powerful and does almost similar tasks like unix cron in java environment.
There are bunch of tutorials online for quartz that you can always look into.